# Pass multiple mock objects to a method

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking, moq

I have a method **CreateAccount** to test. I am using **Moq** for the same.

Under CreateAccount method, there are multiple table insertion methods which belongs to two classes `AccountRepository and BillingRepository`

I have setup the Moq but don't know how to use multiple moq objects.

Below is some code snippet

```
Mock<AccountRepository> moq = new Mock<AccountRepository>();
Mock<BillingRepository> moqBill = new Mock<BillingRepository>();
moq.Setup(x => x.AddTable_1(new AddTable_1 { }));
moq.Setup(x => x.AddTable_2(new AddTable_2 { }));
moqBill.Setup(x => x.Table_3());
```

**CreateAccount** method takes four parameters and its under **ApplicationService** class

```
public class ApplicationService
{
public CreateAccountServiceResponse CreateAccount(AuthenticateApp App, CustomerInfo Customer, ServiceInfo Service, Optional op)
    {
       // SOME VALIDATION CODE   
       //.....................



       // SOME CODE TO SAVE DATA INTO TABLES
       obj_1.AddTable_1(objdata_1);
       obj_1.AddTable_2(objdata_2);
       obj_2.AddTable_3(objdata_3);
    }
}
```

Please suggest some solution. How can these three methods will be skipped ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to provide some means to inject `obj_1` and `obj_2`, since they seem to represent your instances of `AccountRepository` and `BillingRepository`, resp.

Typically, you might want to do this by using constructor injection. Extending the snippet you provided, this might look like this:

```
public class ApplicationService
{
    private readonly AccountRepository _accountRepository;
    private readonly BillingRepository _billingRepository;

    public ApplicationService(AccountRepository accountRepository, BillingRepository billingRepository)
    {
        _accountRepository = accountRepository;
        _billingRepository = billingRepository;
    }

    public CreateAccountServiceResponse CreateAccount(AuthenticateApp App, CustomerInfo Customer, ServiceInfo Service, Optional op)
    {
       // SOME VALIDATION CODE   
       //.....................



       // SOME CODE TO SAVE DATA INTO TABLES
       _accountRepository.AddTable_1(objdata_1);
       _accountRepository.AddTable_2(objdata_2);
       _billingRepository.AddTable_3(objdata_3);
    }
}
```

Now you can inject your mocks into the class under test:

```
public void CreateAccount_WhenCalledLikeThis_DoesSomeCoolStuff()
{
     var accountRepoMock = new Mock<AccountRepository>();
     // set it up
     var billingRepository = new Mock<BillingRepository>();
     // set it up
     var appService = new ApplicationService(accountRepoMock.Object, billingRepoMock.Objcet);

     // More setup

     // Act
     var response = appService.CreateAccount(...);

     // Assert on response and/or verify mocks
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot !!!!!
It works. I was not confident about how to pass multiple MOQ objects. Today I realized the best use of constructors :) :)
Thanksssss

Comment: I have one more challenge, there is one method "CreateLog" under class "ApplicationService"which I want to skip.
How can I achieve that ? Do I need to Pass object to constructor or there is an alternate ?

Comment: @Gaurav123 If you mean that in the code of `CreateAccount` there is a call to `ApplicationService.CreateLog` then you wouldn't want to do anything about it. Moq provides the method on the mocked object, but this implementation does nothing out of the box. Special behaviour can be achieved via `Setup`. Or do I misunderstand you?

Comment: Thanks, yesterday I  used Mock<ApplicationService> moqApplication =new Mock<ApplicationService>();

moqApplication.SetUp(x=>x.CreateLog(partamerters)).Return(string.Empty); 

And its working fine :) :)